# What does "Version is not valid in this context" mean?

Tags: support, documentation

I was trying to edit a topic, and to condense two examples that existed for two separate versions into the same one, differentiating between versions inline. However, I got this message:

[image]

Am I doing it wrong (I also noticed inline versioning is not showing up in the preview), or is this a bug?

Comment: Try to use a specific version like 2.3 or 3.0. I think only those listed in http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/python/193/introduction-to-python#versions are accepted.

Comment: Tried it, and it didn't work :\

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [Markdown help article](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#inline-versions):

> For Documentation with multiple groups of versions (ie. .NET, which has Core and Micro Frameworks), you must include the group name in the HTML comment before the conditional.
>
> ```
> <!-- if version <Named Framework> [gte 2.0] -->
> Content relevant to Named Framework versions 2.0 and greater.
> <!-- end version if -->
> ```

Since Python has [3.x and 2.x version groups](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/python/193/introduction-to-python#versions), you need to add the group:

```
<!-- if version <Python 2.x> [gte 2.3] -->

print('Hello, world')

<!-- end version if -->
```

[image: Hello Python 2.x]

I don't think ranges work with version groups, however.

---

The other thing to note is that the version has to match the list of versions in the introductory topic *at the time the topic is submitted*. Since many minor versions were [removed from the Python tag](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/17363), it may be necessary to [edit versions](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/43207?diffType=SideBySideMarkdown) that already exist in an example even if that's not the edit you'd planned to make.

Comment: I added a link to some stuff outside of any version groups and I received this error.

Comment: Yes, made a trivial edit to a page but had to change someone else's <!-- if version --> tag from 2.7.11 (which was valid at some point) to 2.7 which is now the Python tag. Similarly, changed 3.0.0 to 3.0 and it worked without this annoying pop-up.